# Execute request or subscribe to the result with RxJava

Tags: java, rx-java

I am trying to implement the following logic with RxJava:

1. Execute server request if I don't have value locally
2. Provide result to the subscriber
3. If the request is running do not create a second one, but subscribe to the result of the running request.

The following solution partially solves the problem:

```
private final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

private  Observable<T> getValue(){
    if(storage.getValue() == null) {
        Future<T> futureValue = executor.submit(new Callable<T>() {
            @Override
            public T call() throws Exception {
                return getValueFromStorageOrBackend();
            }
        });
        return Observable.from(futureValue);
    } else {
        return Observable.just(storage.getValue());
    }
}

private String getValueFromStorageOrBackend() {
    final String currentValue = storage.getValue();
    if (currentValue == null) {
        Response response = backend.requestValue();
        storage.setValue(response.getValue());

        return response.getValue();
    }

    return currentValue;
}
```

Is there an elegant pure RxJava solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

One of the simpler ways to do this is via `AsyncSubject` + a compare-and-set loop:

```
final AtomicReference<AsyncSubject<T>> subjectRef = new AtomicReference<>();

public Observable<T> get() {
    for (;;) {
        AsyncSubject<T> subject = subjectRef.get();
        if (subject != null) {
            return subject;
        }
        AsyncSubject<T> next = AsyncSubject.create();
        if (subjectRef.compareAndSet(null, next)) {
            Observable.just(1).map(ignored -> {
                // your computation here
                return 2; // the result
            }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).subscribe(subject);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

I almost forgot, an even more simple way is to use `cache`:

```
Observable
.just(1)
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.map(ignored -> {
    // computation here
    return 2;
}).cache();
```

Comment: In `just(1)` I will return my stored value. In `map()` I will check if the value is `null` and execute the request if needed. Is it correct? What guarantees that the request is executed only once?

Comment: Why is there an infinite loop in the first example?

Comment: It is a CAS loop in case there are concurrent callers to get() and only one should trigger the background computation. There is a `return` there for this case. Due to the state changes, the loop is executed at most twice before it quits.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and how the second example guarantees the call will be made once?

Comment: The `Observable` returned by `cache()` operator subscribes to the upstream `Observable` at most once, when the first `Subscriber` subscribes.