# How to subscribe to execution of a task using RxJava and Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask, rx-java

I am just dipping my toes into RxJava so please be gentle :) I was ok with AsyncTasks up to today but it gets more and more complicated and I think I have finally stumbled upon a requirement that I am actually struggling to fulfil with simple AsyncTasks. This is my use case:

1) I have a method (lets call it `checkNetwork()`) that needs to run once in a session. If it has run previously it returns with cached response. Otherwise it executes a network call and then, depending on the result, executes another one. Both those network tasks are run with OkHttp and are synchronous. The method itself is run from an AsyncTask. For example:

```
public class MyApis{

  private boolean mCachedResult;
  private boolean mNetworkChecked;

  ....

  public boolean checkNetwork() {
    if (mNetworkChecked) {
      return mCachedResult;
    }
    doFirstCall();
    // check response, set flags and potentially return
    doSecondCall();
    // check response, set flags, i.e.

    mCachedResult = response.blah
    mNetworkChecked = true;
  }

  public boolean isNetworkChecked(){
    return mNetworkChecked;
}
```

2) I have multiple parts of my code that will run `isNetworkChecked()` and if not, then call `checkNetwork()`. There can be situations with poor network conditions that `checkNetwork()` will be taking its sweet time and `isNetworkChecked()` will be returning false. This will generate and queue up quite a few of AsyncTasks. Yes those tasks will be resolved very quickly but I'm hitting problems with the default queue size on the Executor.

As far as I understand RxJava can help me with this. What I would like to do is to run `checkNetwork()` only once, and if it is running already, instead of queueing AsyncTasks, simply subscribe, wait for it to finish and execute my code based on the response (i.e. `mCachedResult` in my example).

Comment: This could be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33241262/execute-request-or-subscribe-to-the-result-with-rxjava

Comment: It's very similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30756552/how-wait-observable-result-from-independent-components-in-rxjava

Comment: Thanks! I'll check out both of these and hopefully will come up with my own interpretation!

Answer (score 0):

you could use `fromCallable` with `replay(1)` in RxJava 1.0.15:

```
Observable<Blah> blahs = Observable.fromCallable(() -> {
    doFirstCall();
    doSecondCall();
    return response.blah;
})
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.replay(1).autoConnect(0);

blahs.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.subscribe(...)
```